# Track user status in real time with amazon chime sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I have a messaging application (written with amazon chime sdk), that lets users to create channels and communicate over them. Also users can add each other to something like friend list.

The next step I want to implement is let users track online/offline status in real time in theirs friend list.

Could you please suggest me which aws service I should pick to done this feature?

Thanks!